# IHttpContextAccessor contains empty User.Identity, when used outside of the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing an app ASP.Net Core (2.2) MVC. I need to filter some the data inside the DbContext by value of certain claims of the Logged in user. I inject IHttpContextAccessor, but when I try to access HttpContext.User.Identity - all properties are null and all claims are empty.

This is how I am trying to achieve that 
I wire up IHttpContextAccessor. I use a standard method like that:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
}
```

Then I build a custom Provider to extract claims from the User:

```
public class GetClaimsFromUser : IGetClaimsProvider
{
  public string UserId {get; private set;}

  public GetClaimsFromUser(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
  {
     UserId = accessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
  }
}
```

Then I also inject it inside ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
...
  services.AddScoped<IGetClaimsProvider, GetClaimsFromUser>();
...
}
```

Afterwards I injected it inside the ApplicationDbContext and try to set the private _userId field inside the constructor:

```
public class ExpenseManagerDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  private string _userId;

  public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IGetClaimsProvider claimsProvider) : base(options)
  {
    _userId = claimsProvider.UserId;
    ...
  }
...
}
```

And exactly here it is empty. When I access the HttpContext inside the controller, the User.Identity is not empty and everything is fine. However, when I need to access it outside the controller, it is empty.

Thanks for any help!!!

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/dudelis/expense-manager/blob/master/ExpenseManager.DataAccess/Concrete/EntityFramework/ExpenseManagerDbContext.cs?

Comment: Are you using any async method between controller and context?

Comment: What do you mean by "access it outside the controller"? Are you using a background thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to access the user in `ExpenseManagerDbContext` which is the application’s `IdentityDbContext`. As such, it itself is a dependency of the authentication system and will get resolved when the framework performs the authentication.

So the flow is somewhat like this:

1. Request comes in.
2. Authentication middleware runs to authenticate the user.
3. `UserManager` resolves `ExpenseManagerDbContext`.
4. `ExpenseManagerDbContext` resolves `IGetClaimsProvider`.
5. `GetClaimsProvider` resolves the HttpContext and attempts to access the user’s claims.
6. Authentication middleware performs the authentication and sets `HttpContext.User` with the result.

If you look at steps 5 and 6, you will see that the HttpContext is accessed *before* the authentication middleware is able to actually authenticate the user and update the user object on the context. And since the authentication middleware always runs at the beginning of a request, this will always be the case.

I would recommend you to rethink your `ExpenseManagerDbContext` since it probably shouldn’t depend on the currently signed-in user. It should be independent of that. If you have logic there that depends on the user id, then it should probably be a separate service.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
The problem was in the sharing of the same DbContext for IdentityDbContext and ApplicationDataDbContext.
In my controller I had the following code:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      var accounts = _accountService.GetAll();
      var models = _mapper.Map<List<AccountDto>>(accounts);
      return View(models);
   }
}
```

And when I tried to call the controller from the browser, the app initialized DbContext first time due to [Authorize] attribute. And this was done without any HttpContext. So when the application made a call to the DbContext in '_accountService.GetAll()', the DbContext was already instantiated and the Constructor method was not called, therefore, all my private fields remained empty!
So I created a second DbContext class only for authentication/authorization purposes.

```
public class ApplicationDbAuthContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbAuthContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbAuthContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Due to this, during the request inside the controller the correct DbContext was instantiated when I made a call and it contained the HttpContext.

I will update my code in the repo to show the changes.
Meanwhile, thanks for all the answers.